# What is the minimum Mac OS Partition size when using Boot Camp on a Macbook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro

And does it vary with 128GB or 256GB size hard drives?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this would depend on the type of Mac or hard drive. Instead, it should only depend on the **version of OS X** that you're running.

While Apple's documentations for [OS X 10.7 Lion](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP629) state **7 GB** as a required minimum, BootCamp 4.0.3 allows a minimum of **8GB** for the OS X partition. Probably, because this includes the **650 MB** for the [recovery partition (end of page)](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP629).